# "only protocol 3 supported" error when trying to connect to Postgresl Database through Django

Tags: python, django, postgresql, psycopg2

```
Windows 10 x64     
Python 3.6
psycopg2==2.8.3
PostgreSQL 9.1.1.2-1.1C(x64)
Django 2.2.1
```

When trying to execute query to database I get an error "only protocol 3 supported"

I run:

`python manage.py makemigrations`

I got a big pile of errors with the

```
django.db.utils.InterfaceError: only protocol 3 supported
```

in the end.

[image]

psql

`\list`
[image]

The settings.py `DATABASES = {}` SECTION is set up with valid credentials

I can even connect to db using them
[image]

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: I think you should read [this](https://tutorial-extensions.djangogirls.org/en/optional_postgresql_installation/#postgresql-installation)

Comment: @Goran Installed the latest version of Postgres and everything works fine